# Curved line through points

Tags: graphing-functions

[image: Chart Example]

I would like to be able to do something like this in c++.

How can I go about creating a nice curved line like this through a list of points?

Can anyone please point me in the direction of the relevant maths?

Edit 1:

Here is another example of what I would like from the output.

[image: Graph 2]

I need to be able to calculate Y for any given X...

Edit 2:

Please don't just post existing APIs, chances are they will be useless on an MCU. I would prefer reading the maths...

Comment: Look up "cubic spline"

Comment: In addition to cubic splines and splines in general, maybe these pointers can help as some are open source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481209/beautiful-charting-graphing-scientific-plotting

Comment: These may also be helpful: http://linux.about.com/od/howtos/l/blsc6.htm

Comment: I have been playing with them already... well bezier cubic splines... but its too complicated to work out the Y for any given X (which I need to do).

Is there a version of cubic/quadratic splines which would allow me to do this?

Comment: What's an API? What's an MCU?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up some notes on cubic splines, just a couple of pages about a third of the way through these [notes](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/math133s211/notes/Applications.pdf). I think the calculations are not too hard.

Comment: +1, Thank you for sharing this information, very readable.

Comment: Just printed it out. Very good resource. Thanks so much!

Comment: ...will get back to you on the difficulty when i try it :)

Comment: The problem with this is its assumes equally spaced points... which my points will definitely not be :(

Great text though

Comment: Yes, you're right (although the example you gave in the original question has equally spaced points). The calculations are more difficult when the points are not equally spaced, and I'm afraid I have nothing written up - but my guess is that if you keep looking you'll find it written up somewhere, and the formulas won't be all that bad for computing.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to consider the method of Quadratic Least Square Regression. For an example in C# see [CodeProject-Least Square Regression for Quadratic Curve](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63170/Least-Squares-Regression-for-Quadratic-Curve-Fitti).

The point to notice is that such methods make assumptions about the function value for the data you don't provide. For example, it assumes that data at $x=4.5$. Such assumptions may not be correct.

I assume that Excel is using QR Decomposition method to produce your chart.

For starters, this introduction may help: [Seminar-Curve Fitting](http://kobus.ca/seminars/ugrad/NM5_curve_s02.pdf)

Comment: Curve-fitting and interpolation are not the same thing! Least-squares won't ensure that the curve goes through the given points.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I suggested curve fitting because I am not sure what method Excel uses.

Comment: I dont want a single quadratic formula (which I believe this technique will give me). I want to ensure I strike straight through every point and just curve off to some acceptable degree between each point. See edit 1, above.

Comment: Do you always have fixed number of points? How many points are you expected to have?

Comment: an unspecified amount :)

Comment: Well, if you had small number of points, say N, one could use a specific polynomial of degree <= N (where N is how many data points you have). Such an algorithm may call for solving N simultaneous equations, but as per your case, I don't think that this would work for you.